# Docker container won't restart because there's no room

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I use the command:

```
sudo dockerd
```

I keep getting this error :

> Error starting daemon: Unable to get the TempDir under /var/lib/docker: mkdir /var/lib/docker/tmp: no space left on device

I have tried prune but then I get :

> Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?

Comment: Can you check once the disk space using du or df command at location /var/lib/docker/

Comment: @ShaktirajsinhJadeja it tells me permission denied.

Comment: Probably you just don't have the correct privileges. Check your user and the owner/group and permissions on the target directory.

Comment: use sudo to execute command ...hope your user have sudo permissions.